# How do I deal with two situations that could be candidates for a strategy pattern solution?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am designing a client that will call methods based on certain inputs.  I will be sending in a billing system enum and calling an endpoint to determine which billing system is appropriate for an existing patient.  Once I get the billing system, I have to check to see what type of operation I need to perform and make an API call based on the billing system.

For example, if I need to update a patient record and the patient is in BillingSystemA, I need to call a PUT-based method of the API for BillingSystemA.

I need to have CRUD methods for each billing system.

Selecting between the two billing systems and allowing for future growth made me think that the strategy pattern was a good fit.  Strategy seems to work for the billing system, but what about the CRUD operations?

I have a `BillingStrategy` abstract class that has `Create`, `Update`, `Get` and `Delete` methods, but I need those methods to work against a variety of types.  Can I just make the methods generic, like `T Create<T>` or `bool Update<T>` or do I need a strategy within a strategy to manage this?  I've analyzed myself into a corner and could use some advice.

Comment: Does the value of the `enum` alone tell you which billing system to use, or do you have to actually call an endpoint to find out? Also, what's an example of the sort of transaction you're trying to execute - even a few words? That will make it easier to provide an example. It also helps to take CRUD out of the picture. Way behind the scenes the implementation may or may not be some CRUD-type activity, but external operations - the thing your application does - are likely easier to work with if they don't sound like CRUD operations.

Comment: Maybe Strategy over Facade?  Use Strategy in the way you've described, and wrap each billing system in a Facade to address the "variety of types".

Comment: An endpoint is being developed that will return a `BillingSystemType` enum value for existing patients.  New patients are always created in `BillingSystemA`.  Upon receiving the billing system type, I need to call the API of that billing system, which is essentially equivalent to a CRUD operation, i.e., I'll be calling `billingSystemA.Create<Patient>()` or `billingSystemB.Create<SalesOrder>` or `billingSystemA.Update<Patient>(patientId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough illustration. I invented a lot of the specifics, and the names aren't so great. I tend to revisit names as I refactor. The main point is to illustrate how we can break up the problem into pieces.

This assumes that there are classes for `Patient`and `Treatment` and an enum for `InsuranceType`. The goal is to bill a patient for a treatment, and determine where to send the bill based on the patient's insurance.

Here's a class:

```
public class PatientBilling
{
    private readonly IBillingHandlerByInsuranceSelector _billingHandlerSelector;
    private readonly IBillingHandler _directPatientBilling;

    public PatientBilling(
        IBillingHandlerByInsuranceSelector billingHandlerSelector, 
        IBillingHandler directPatientBilling)
    {
        _billingHandlerSelector = billingHandlerSelector;
        _directPatientBilling = directPatientBilling;
    }

    public void BillPatientForTreatment(Patient patient, Treatment treatment)
    {
        var billingHandler = _billingHandlerSelector.GetBillingHandler(patient.Insurance);
        var result = billingHandler.BillSomeone(patient, treatment);
        if (!result.Accepted)
        {
            _directPatientBilling.BillSomeone(patient, treatment);
        }
    }
}
```

and a few interfaces:

```
public interface IBillingHandler
{
    BillSomeoneResult BillSomeone(Patient patient, Treatment treatment);
}

public interface IBillingHandlerByInsuranceSelector
{
    IBillingHandler GetBillingHandler(InsuranceType insurance);
}
```

As you can see this will rely heavily on dependency injection. This class is simple because it doesn't know anything at all about the different insurance types.

All it does is

- Select a billing handler based on the insurance type
- try to submit the bill to the insurance
- if it's rejected, bill the patient

It doesn't know or care how any of that billing is implemented. It could be a database call, an API call, or anything else. That makes this class very easy to read and test. We've deferred whatever isn't related to this class. That's going to make it easier to solve future problems one at a time.

The implementation of `IBillingHandlerByInsuranceSelector` can be an abstract factory that will create and return the correct implementation of `IBillingHandler` according to the patient's insurance. (I'm glossing over that but there's plenty of information on how to create abstract factories with dependency injection containers.)

In a sense we could say that the first part of this problem is solved (although we're likely to refactor some more.) The reason why is that we can write unit tests for it, and any of the work specific to one insurance type or another will be in different classes.

Next we can write those insurance-specific implementations. Suppose one of the insurance types is WhyCo, and now we need to create an `IBillingHandler` for them. We're essentially going to repeat the same process.

For the sake of illustration, let's say that submitting a bill to WhyCo is done in two steps. First we have to make a request to check eligibility, and then we have to submit the bill. Maybe other insurance APIs do this in one step. That's okay, because no two implementations have to have anything in common with each other. They just implement the interface.

At this point we're dealing with the specifics of one particular insurance company, so somewhere in here we'll need to convert our `Patient` and `Treatment` information into whatever data they expect to receive.

```
public class WhyCoBillingHandler : IBillingHandler
{
    private readonly IWhyCoService _whyCoService;

    public WhyCoBillingHandler(IWhyCoService whyCoService)
    {
        _whyCoService = whyCoService;
    }

    public BillSomeoneResult BillSomeone(Patient patient, Treatment treatment)
    {
        // populate this from the patient and treatment
        WhyCoEligibilityRequest eligibilityRequest = ...;
        var elibility = _whyCoService.CheckEligibility(eligibilityRequest);
        if(!elibility.IsEligible)
            return new BillSomeoneResult(false, elibility.Reason);

        // create the bill
        WhyCoBillSubmission bill = ...;
        _whyCoService.SubmitBill(bill);
        return new BillSomeoneResult(true);
    }
}

public interface IWhyCoService
{
    WhyCoEligibilityResponse CheckEligibility(WhyCoEligibilityRequest request);
    void SubmitBill(WhyCoBillSubmission bill);
}
```

At this point we still haven't written any code that talks to the WhyCo API. That makes `WhyCoBillingHandler` easy to unit test. Now we can write an implementation of `IWhyCoService` that calls the actual API. We can write unit tests for `WhyCoBillingHandler` and integration tests for the implementation of `IWhyCoService`.

(Perhaps it would have been better if translating our `Patient` and `Treatment` data into what they expect happened even closer to the concrete implementation.)

At each step we're writing pieces of the code, testing them, and deferring parts for later. The API class might be the last step in implementing WhyCo billing. Then we can move on to the next insurance company.

At each step we also decide how much should go into each class. Suppose we have to write a private method, and that method ends up being so complicated that it's bigger than the public method that calls it and it's hard to test. That might be where we replace that private method with another dependency (abstraction) that we inject into the class.

Or we might realize up front that some new functionality should be separated into its own class, and we can just start off with that.

---

The reason why I illustrated it this way is this:

> I've analyzed myself into a corner

It's easy to become paralyzed when our code has to do so many things. This helps to avoid paralysis because it continually gives us a path forward. We write part of it to depend on abstractions, and then that part is done (sort of.) Then we implement those abstractions. The implementations require more abstractions, and we repeat (writing unit tests all the way in between.)

This doesn't enforce best practices and principles, but it gently guides us toward them. We're writing small, single-responsibility classes. They depend on abstractions. We're defining those abstractions (interfaces, in this case) from the perspective of the classes that need them, which leads to interface segregation. And each class is easy to unit test.

Some will point out that it's easy to get carried away with all the abstractions and create too many interfaces and too many layers of abstraction, and they are correct. But that's okay. At every single step we're likely to go a little off balance one way or the other.

As you can see, the problems that occur when we have to deal with the difference between billing systems becomes simpler. We just create every implementation differently.

> Strategy seems to work for the billing system, but what about the CRUD operations?

The fact that they all have different CRUD operations is fine. We've made components similar where they need to be similar (the interfaces through which we interact with them) but the internal implementations can be as different as they need to be.

We've also sidestepped the question of which design patterns to use, except that `IBillingHandlerByInsuranceSelector` is an abstract factory. That's okay too, because we don't want to start off too focused on a design pattern. If this was a real application, I'd assume that a lot of what I'm doing will need to be refactored. Because the classes are small, unit tested, and depend on abstractions, it's easier to introduce design patterns when their use becomes obvious. When that happens we can likely isolate them to the classes that need them. Or, if we've just realized that we've gone in the wrong direction, it's still easier to refactor. Unless we can see the future that's certain to happen.

It's worth taking some time up front to understand the various implementation details to make sure that the way you have to work with them lines up with the code you're writing. (In other words, we still need to spend some time on design.) For example, if your billing providers don't give you immediate responses - you have to wait hours or days - then code that models it as an immediate response wouldn't make sense.

One more benefit is that this helps you to work in parallel with other developers. If you've determined that a given abstraction is a good start for your insurance companies and maybe you've written a few, then it's easy to hand off other ones to other developers. They don't have to think about the whole system. They can just write an implementation of an interface, creating whatever dependencies they need to.

Comment: Wow, this is a very comprehensive and well thought out answer.  I will take some time to digest it and apply it, but I get the message that I should work through the problem to see if a pattern fits, rather than trying to fit a pattern to my problem.